# Using Service Reference to both serialize and deserialize XML

Tags: c#, xml, api, soap

This is a bit of a weird one. I recently started working with C# and have been tasked with parsing incoming soapxml from an API response. I'm currently parsing the data manually like this:

```
var agency ="";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);
    XNamespace ns = "urn:Blurbe";
    var result = doc.Root.Descendants(ns + "IdentificationResponse")
                    .Descendants("IdentificationResult")
                    .Descendants("e")
                    .Descendants("r")
                    .Descendants("agence");
 
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.ToString()))
        agency = result.FirstOrDefault().Value;
return agency
```

Although this works, obviously it's quite tedious to have to do it for every element and attribute that I want to extract. So, I have been asked to use service reference to serialize and deserialize the soapxml so that it can easily be reference with dot notations, and easy to save into DB.

Anyone know how I can go about doing this - any example?
Any help would be appreciated.

Helen

Comment: Take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/framework/query-xpathdocument-xpath-csharp - you can make your code much simpler by using XPath => "urn:Blurbe:IdentificationResponse/IdentificationResult/e/r/agence"

Comment: Thanks @slacker - I will take a look at that link.

Comment: @HelenNeely: If the SOAP service you are interacting with has a WSDL, you can generate client code from that WSDL and that will allow you to work with objects as opposed to raw XML (all of the marshaling/unmarshaling will be handled by the generated client code for you). Using a service reference is similar with using something like [svcutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe) to generate code.

Comment: @HelenNeely: you might also want to read these [Use the WCF Web Service Reference Provider Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide) and [The WSDL is not the SOAP web service](https://d-petre-bogdan.medium.com/the-wsdl-is-not-the-soap-web-service-97f307c4a90b)

Comment: Hey @Bogdan, thanks for your tips and the links, will explore them and see if they help. Thanks.